# Laravel: TinyMCE Upload Images

Tags: php, laravel-5, tinymce

I want to upload images insinde the TinyMCE editor. I found instructions for that [in the docs](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/upload-images/).

These are my Javascript settings:

```
tinymce.init({ 
       selector: '#about',          
       images_upload_url: '/home/profile/about/img',
     });

tinymce.activeEditor.uploadImages(function(success) {
      $.post('/home/profile/about/img', tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()).done(function() {
        console.log("Uploaded images and posted content as an ajax request.");
      });
    });
```

I created the following route to check if everything is setup correctly

```
Route::post('/home/profile/about/img', function(){
 return json_encode(['location' => '/storage/app/public/pictures/bestAvatar.png' ]);
});
```

I expected that when I upload an image nothing will be uploaded and the image `bestAvatar.png` is shown - however instead I get an error:

[image]

Am I missing anything? Is it maybe because there is no default csrf token in the tinymce ajax call?

Comment: Add your route to routes/api.php instead of web.php and you won't need the CSRF token

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
tinymce.init({ 
       selector: '#about',          
       images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
           var xhr, formData;
           xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xhr.withCredentials = false;
           xhr.open('POST', '/home/profile/about/img');
           var token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
           xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
           xhr.onload = function() {
               var json;
               if (xhr.status != 200) {
                   failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                   return;
               }
               json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

               if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                   failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                   return;
               }
               success(json.location);
           };
           formData = new FormData();
           formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
           xhr.send(formData);
       }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have a right.
Try to add:

```
'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
```

to the ajax header

Answer (score 1):

In general 419 error is csrf token error which means you need to add

```
protected $except = [
    //
    '/upload',
];
```

in your VerifyCsrToken.php file.

Follow the link to get more understanding
[About TinyMCE 419 Error in Laravel](https://www.dbestech.com/tutorials/easiest-way-to-upload-image-in-laravel)

I experienced the same problem. Check it out in my website how to solve this problem.

Comment: You appear to be the author of the linked article.
When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam.
Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: Ok. I got it. I am new. How do I make it more sufficient.?

Comment: At the minimum, you need to disclose affiliation. So you could simply add "*I am the author of the linked article*". In general, note that you should only add a link when it's relevant to the question. Also, you shouldn't make a habit of linking to your articles; doing it a couple of times is ok, but doing it too frequently is not allowed.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification. I got it.